# Control which devices connect to which USB port on startup

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with a GPS module and an ELM327 adaptor both connected to USB ports. Typically, the GPS module comes up on /dev/ttyUSB0 and the ELM adaptor on /dev/ttyUSB1, which is fine, however every once in a while they will swap ports.  This tends to upset my python scripts running on the device.

Is there a way I can control/configure which device will connect to which port? Is it a first come first serve when assigning port numbers?

Running Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Have you considered adding logic to detect a specific device to your Python code instead of trying to control the enumeration? Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110310/simple-way-to-query-connected-usb-devices-info-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487033/usb-device-identification. This would seem to be a more foolproof/futureproof solution.

Comment: I had considered it but was hoping to avoid it.  I had a look at the posts you suggested.  Although `pyUSB` showed the most promise, it still didn't quite hit the mark, as any `dev.filename` always came back `None`.  But it did send me in a direction, and this is what I came up with:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I came up with...  may not be pretty, but gives me what I needed...

```
import subprocess

devices = {}
# put all dmesg messages into a list
output_list = []
output_list = str(subprocess.check_output('dmesg')).split('\\n')

# Look for 'New USB device' messages   
filter_list = [x for x in output_list if 'New USB device found' in x]
for f in filter_list:
    # This message gives us vendor, product and bus ID's
    bus_id = f.split(':')[0].split(']')[1].strip()
    devices[bus_id] = {}
    devices[bus_id]['VENDOR'] =  f.split(',')[1].strip().split('=')[1]
    devices[bus_id]['PRODUCT'] =  f.split(',')[2].strip().split('=')[1]
    # list to store all other details about the device
    device_details = []
    # pull out all messages from dmesg in relation to the bus ID
    device_details = [x for x in output_list if bus_id in x]
    # Pick out the info we need:
    for d in device_details:
        if 'Product:' in d:
            # Product Name
            devices[bus_id]['NAME'] = d.split(':')[2].strip()
            if 'Manufacturer' in d:
                # Manufacturer Name
                devices[bus_id]['MANUFACTURER'] = d.split(':')[2].strip()
            if 'now attached to' in d:
                # Block device - if it has one 
                devices[bus_id]['FILE'] = d.split('now attached to')[1].strip()

for dev in devices:
    print('USB Bus ID: {}'.format(dev))
        for prop in devices[dev]:
            print('  {} = {}'.format(prop, devices[dev][prop]))
```

Comment: [Udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) will do this kind of thing for you (have a look at any file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and you should get the idea).  Also try `udevadm monitor` and watch what happens when you plug a device in and out. There's lots of stuff online about this, just don't include "raspberry pi" in your search terms; use "linux".  It's been around for a long time.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

I use pmount, and it does a very good job of keeping USB devices consistent.

You can get it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install pmount
```

It works great for serial and flash drive devices, so it is definitely worth a try.

Comment: Ill take a look when I get a chance... Cheers...  My code work-around is a bit of an ugly hack, but works as long as devices aren't removed and added later on different ports (should be OK for an embedded pi system...)